# getting error "Unable to load 'foo.dll' ", How asp.net application loads all the DLLs required to run the application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting this error in my application "Unable to load DLL 'foo.dll' .The specified module couldn't be found. I was using this dll in my application and now it is not referenced any more.

I looked at all the references,All  nuget packages directories,packages config,csproj file and this dll name is not found anywhere. I also verified if any dependencies but no luck.

I want to find when and how or what scenarios asp.net loads a particular dll from certain location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following are the main scenarios which asp.net loads dlls

- Your reference dlls and dependencies of referenced dlls
- You are not referring a dll but you can dynamically load the dlls using Reflection
- dll present in your bin directory
- CLR profilers dynamically inject DLLs to the process

Please refer this [msdn](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rohithrajan/2017/06/29/when-and-how-does-asp-net-runtime-load-dlls/) blog for more details .

Hope this helps!